# Create Regular Expression with exact 2 repetition of single character

Tags: regex, scala

I am fighting with regular expression.  I want to create one for validation in REST resource; the id which is queried needs to have two colons, for example  `key1:key2:key3`

How can I create it?  The length of keys 1-3 can change and are not equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `([a-zA-Z\d]+):([a-zA-Z\d]+):([a-zA-Z\d]+)` to select that 'expression'. [Demonstration](http://regexr.com/3cjk1)

Comment: Why not just `([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+)` ?

Comment: I assumed the keys are numbers and letters only.